# Azure logic app returns a parse JSON error

Tags: azure, logic

Have built an Azure logic app with a HTTP trigger that receives a JSON file, provides a response, then attempts to send the payload to a Service Bus queue. Kept getting an status 400 error, so tried adding a parse JSON step, however am getting an invalid template per shot below.
[Azure logic app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQXGJ.png)

[parse JSON error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNGh8.png)
The response is working correctly, with the payload being correctly displayed at the initiating website.
[successful response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZf2r.png)

The JSON data in the schema is as follows. **EDIT:** Revised schema to include "null" per Rick's suggestion below.

```
{
"items": {
    "properties": {
        "Entry Price": {
            "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
            ]
        },
        "Exit Price": {
            "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
            ]
        },
        "Gain $": {
            "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
            ]
        },
        "New Stop": {
            "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
            ]
        },
        "ReceivedDate": {
            "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
            ]
        },
        "ReceivedTime": {
            "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
            ]
        },
        "Status": {
            "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
            ]
        },
        "Stop": {
            "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
            ]
        },
        "Symbol": {
            "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
            ]
        },
        "Tranche": {
            "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
            ]
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "Symbol",
        "Status",
        "ReceivedDate",
        "ReceivedTime"
    ],
    "type": "object"
},
"type": "array"
```

}
I have spent days looking at forums and trying a number of  suggested fixes, however am unable to get the app to execute without error.

Appreciate any ideas or suggestions to fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing in a `null` value for the property `content`, while the schema has it as a required property.

You can solve this by changing the definition in the schema for `content` to be as follows:

```
"content":{
  "type":[
    "string",
    "null"
  ]
}
```

More information (and source) here: [Parsing JSON with null-able properties in Logic Apps](https://adatis.co.uk/parsing-json-with-null-able-properties-in-logic-apps/)

> There is also default values, that could be considered, but everything depends on the context your logic app operates in.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Rick.  I tried the adding the "null" to the schema as per your suggestion, but getting the same error.  Revised schema posted above.  Have also posted the successful return back to the website which shows the payload data.